# SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation

Please find the list below where I'm storing Purchase Order Details and updating "Balance Qty" using SP Designer 2013 workflow.
[image]

Now my requirement is to create one more list to issue the Part No from available Balance Qty in above List "Purchase Order".Below is my new list details which I'm going to create

List Name = "Issue Order"

Issue No, Part No, Balance Qty, Issue Qty, Issue Date, Remaining Balance Qty OR Stock Qty

In this second list through lookup column I can call the "Part No" from List but not clear on how to create SP Designer 2013 workflow for below two points :- 
1) After selecting the part no (using Lookup column) in list 2 how to call Balance Qty from List 1 using SP Designer workflow. 
2) Once part no will issue from list 2 how to update the "Balance Qty" in List1. Can you please help me to provide some guide or steps to create SP Designer 2013 workflow for these two points.

Reason to create new list -  In above print screen we are storing the part no with available Qty which have access for Store Department. Now for Sales Department person we don't want to give access for this list and create separate list for them where they can check the available balance Qty for every part no and if they are going to use any parts, they will out the part no with Issue Qty, Issue No, Issue Date etc from this list. Once they will click save / ok for the Out Qty in List2, Same Qty will be deducted from Balance Qty for the particular part no from Store Department List1. So the reason behind to create on more list is to track the record when the Qty has out also both department have different list for IN and OUT with all details.

Comment: Can you provide more details? like what is out quantity, what do you want to happen in list 2 and why.

Comment: Devang-Thanks for your advice. I've edit the question and added in more detail about my issue with print screen.

Comment: Now my requirement is to create one more list to issue the Part No from available Balance Qty in above List "Purchase Order".

still not clear, how Part No is related to available Balance Qty, what is relation between two, Why you want seperate list.

You can share, what you want to achieve, if allowed in simple words.

Comment: Please find the detail above as here I'm not able to add more details.Reason to create new list -

Comment: then why don't you edit the question? and inlcude all the details

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I thought that much information is enough. Now I've added all the information. Please have a look.

Comment: Devang-Can you please help how to archive this using SP Designer.